# Pendingintent open file not show right file in android Oreo

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent

I have a problem with pending intent open file when click notification.

It doesn't show the right file:

Activity.java

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    if (canReadWriteExternal()) {

    }else {
        requestPermission();
    }

    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
            channelId, channelName, importance);
    mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context, "0");
    String AUTHORITY = "com.package.project";


    File f = new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "myfolder"), attachArr[1]);

    intent = new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);

    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, AUTHORITY, f);
    intent.setData(uri);


    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP &
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP &
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1212, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mNotifyManager.notify(1212, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<provider
        android:name=".Util.LegacyCompatFileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.acs.lupirka"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

provider_paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path path="Android/data/" name="files_root" />
    <external-path path="Download/" name="Download" />
</paths>
```

Comment: Please note: questions here should be "self contained", linking to *other* places isn't a good idea (you want people to read the question as is, to understand what it is about). Thus I pulled in your linked content. But I would ask you to read [mcve] and further adjust your question.

Comment: sorry about that, I gotta problem with attach some code in stackoverflow, could you help me to solve my problem about Pendingintent to setData or contentData from external download folder, my problem is, when I'm click notification finishing download, the apps don't opening the file

Comment: I am not an Android expert. And please: dont put such information into *comments*. All relevant information should be *in* the question.